# Google Cloud SQL selecting rows that don't exist within another table

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-sql

I have a need to audit some data, however I'm running into a roadblock with a query not returning. What can I do differently here as I truly don't understand whey these queries are returning (executed from mysql workbench) even after letting them run for multiple hours? Am i just under provisioned?

I have a n1-standard 4 google cloud sql instance (4cpu, 15GB ram). The two tables are below. There also exists an index on customer_id for table one. Table 2 has 885481 rows and Table 1 has 1891653 rows.

I've tried three variants of a query to look for customer ids in table one where they don't exist in table 2 (represented as account_group_id).

What I would have expected to be most performant and actually return:

```
Select customer_id
FROM Table1 as a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    Select account_group_id
    FROM Table2 as b WHERE b.account_group_id = a.customer_id
)
```

As a sub query:

```
Select customer_id
FROM Table1
WHERE customer_id NOT IN(
    Select account_group_id
    FROM Table2
)
```

As a left join:

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM Table1 as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 as b ON a.customer_id = b.account_group_id
WHERE b.account_group_id IS NULL
```

EDIT: 
So after some tinkering and actually using EXPLAIN before posting my question, the table2 subquery is performing a FULL TABLE scan for some reason. I've tried this query on my test / staging environments with the same index pattens and I'm seeing an index seek there. Now, I'm even more confused. [image: full table scan]

Even if I add a force index hint the query optimizer refuses to use the primary key.

This is what the query plan looks like on my staging environment:

[image]

Any thoughts as to why this is occurring?

Table1:

[image: Table 1]

Table 2:

[image: Table 2]

Comment: in the third variant you need a left join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after much tinkering I completely reworked this query to make the silly optimizer use the index I wanted...must be something to do with the size of the tables:

```
SELECT a.customer_id
FROM Table1 as a
WHERE a.customer_id NOT IN (
    SELECT b.customer_id
    FROM Table1 as b
    JOIN (select account_group_id from Table2) as x on x.account_group_id = b.customer_id
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Make sure table 2 has an INDEX on `account_group_id`. Otherwise, you're doing a full table scan, not efficient.
2. The `SUB QUERY` option is the better bet, but not `OUTER JOIN` as it multiplies both tables rows together, getting a horrible (and seemingly never ending!) result set.

If the index does not exist

```
 -- CREATING AN INDEX IN CASE
 CREATE INDEX T2_agi ON Table2(account_group_id);     

 SELECT customer_id
 FROM Table1 as a
 WHERE customer_id NOT IN(
   Select account_group_id
   FROM Table2
 );
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. There isn't a index on the account_group_id, but that is the primary key. I perhaps have a misunderstanding here as I had an understanding that the primary key would fulfill this.

Comment: Yes, the `PRIMARY KEY` is actually the best `INDEX`.  Try an `EXPLAIN` on the query. The syntax is basically stick the word `EXPLAIN` in front of the query!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I should have used explain before posting my question. Its pretty clear that the primary index is being ignored for some reason on the sub query as per my edits. Any thoughts as too what to try?